# Struggling to translate SQL Query to Linq in a Domain Services Class and Entity Data Model

Tags: sql, linq, group-by, anonymous

Visual Studio 2008 | Silverlight 3 | SQL Server 2005 | Domain Services Class | Entity Data Model

I have a database table "Students" with columns FirstName, LastName, Semester, ProgramOfStudy, Column etc.......

The goal is to return a **Total** (number of students grouped by first letter of lastname), based on the first letter of the lastname of all students in a given **Semester** and **Programofstudy**.

Here is the SQL which works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT LEFT(lastName, 1) AS 'LastNameStartsWith', COUNT(*) AS 'Total', academicPeriod, programCode
FROM         dbo.UM_Students
GROUP BY LEFT(lastName, 1), academicPeriod, programCode
ORDER BY programCode, academicPeriod, 'LastNameStartsWith'
```

Here is the LINQ that works in LinqPad:

```
var query = from c in UM_Students
            where c.AcademicPeriod == 200980 && c.ProgramCode == "BSED-ELED-ED"
            group c by c.LastName[0] into cg
            select new { LastNameStartsWith = cg.Key.ToString(), Total = cg.Count(), AcademicPeriod = 200980, ProgramCode =  "BSED-ELED-ED" };
query.Dump();
```

I am unsuccessful in translating this to my Domain Services class.  The main issue has been getting the return type wrong and dealing with anonymous Types.

Here is my effort so far:

```
public List<lastLetterCounts> GetAlphaCount(int cycleID, string programCode)
{
    List<lastLetterCounts> query = (from c in db.UM_StudentSet
        where c.academicPeriod == 200980 && c.programCode == "BSED-ELED-ED"
        group c by c.lastName[0] into cg
        select new lastLetterCounts { LastNameStartsWith = cg.Key.ToString(), Total = cg.Count(), academicPeriod = cycleID, programCode = programCode }).ToList();

    return query;
}

public class lastLetterCounts
{
    [Key]
    public string LastNameStartsWith { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int academicPeriod { get; set; }
    public string programCode { get; set; }
}
```

The Solution compiles and executes, but does not return any data.  I don't know how to debug it as the linq evaluates as one big chunk.

This same problem is being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300562/querying-a-sql-view-with-linq-in-a-domain-services-class-and-entity-data-model) but with a different approach.

Comment: Why do you have to do this in linq? Just use a stored proc and return what you want to return. It is real easy if you are using Linq to Sql and a little more challenging in Entity Framework v1, but probably the best way to go.

Comment: awright18, thanks for the reply.  I did do this in a stored procedure and entitity framework.  It returned the same results as I described in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300562/querying-a-sql-view-with-linq-in-a-domain-services-class-and-entity-data-model.  I will try it as linq to sql, and will post back  how it works out.

Comment: awright18, I was successful in doing this with Linq to SQL class and WCF Service.  It worked as Stored Procedure, as querying a view in the DBML and as, the grouping LINQ.  So that means something isn't working right with the Entity Framework.

It would be nice to know what is going wrong.